# Remove blank propertyColumn from swing tableModel

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

I would like to remove en empty propertyColumn  from tableModel. Is there any function which returns its content?
Next I should use removeColumn() yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you don't remove the data from the `TableModel`. Typically you would just remove the column from the view of the `JTable`:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn( "..." ) );
```

The data will still be accessible in from the `TableModel`.

If you really want to remove the data then you can use a `DefaultTableModel` which supports a `setColumnCount(...)` method. However this will only allow you to remove columns at the end of the model. If you want to remove columns of data in the middle then you need to implement your own custom method.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

And do you know how to return column content?

Comment: You get the data from the TableModel - `table.getModel().getValueAt(...)`.